# Angular 2: Is there an easy way using FormBuilder with FormArray in ng2?

Tags: forms, angular, formbuilder

## Situation

I'm working on a form where I want to list some mails having a checkbox besides the subject and a "check all" checkbox in the same column as the other checkboxes.

The form looks simply like this:

```
[ ] Check all
------------------------------------------
[ ] This is email subject #1
[ ] This is email subject #2
[ ] ...
```

- When I select `Check all` all the below checkboxes should be selected and when I click again, all mails should be unselected.
- The mails are coming dynamically into the component via an `@Input` and the list can change at any point of time.

So far so easy, nothing special. BUT it seems not so easy when using the FormBuilder in ng2 for that. Side note: I want to use the FormBuilder to test my code less end-to-end but more with unit tests.

## Current code

#### Template

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <div><input formControlName="toggleAll" type="checkbox"></div>

  <div>
    <ul formArrayName="checkMailList">
      <li *ngFor="let mail of mails; let i=index">
        <input type="checkbox" [formControlName]="i">
        <div>mail.subject</div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</form>
```

#### Component

```
@Component({ ... })
export class MailListComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input() mails: Mail[];

  private get checkMailList(): FormArray { return this.form.get('checkMailList') as FormArray; }

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      checkMailList: this.fb.array([]);
    });
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (!changes['mails'] || !changes['mails'].currentValue) {
      return;
    }

    // remove array first from form, as we will get 
    // mails again when anything updates
    if (this.checkMailList.length > 0) {
      this.form.removeControl('checkMailList');
      this.form.addControl('checkMailList', this.fb.array([]));
    }

    this.mails.forEach(m => {
      this.checkMailList.push(this.fb.control());
    });

    this.form
      .valueChanges
      .pluck('toggleAll')
      .distinctUntilChanged()
      .subscribe(selectAll => {
        if (selectAll) {
          this.checkMailList.setValue(this.mails.map(_ => true));
        } else {
          this.checkMailList.reset();
        }
      });
  }
}
```

## Problem

- I think that there could occur a race condition/timing issue: I iterate over the `mails` array provided by `@Input` but I wire the `checkMailList` manually in the template to the corresponding index. I iterate over all `mails` whenever the `@Input` changes. I don't know if Angular first iterates over all `mails` in the template and then runs the `ngOnChange` method or vice versa. Can anyone can give me a profounded answer here?

Forms are the fundamental part of every WebApp. Am I doing it right? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what if you did a get set on the input and repopulated the form control there?